# App logo is not changing in android lollipop 5.0.2 version

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

The app logo on updating the app is not changing for my Moto G 1st Generation phone. Also I've two apps as "Google Photos". Don't know what to do with that??

Help!

Comment: Check if Guest User is active.

Comment: have you check in manifest this line to change icon  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" if you have dun it

Comment: remove bin files and cleen project

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the Project by going to

1.**Eclipse->Project->Clean** it will rebuild the .apk file.

2. Make sure that both 'Google Photos' apps should have different package name as well.
3. In the resource folder the image files should have name in lowercase only, or else the XML will not able to get it, eg; file name Should not be like this Image.png, it should be image.png.

Answer (score 0):

Possible that you have different drawables for ic_launcher or logo in your hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi folders.